# How to download files or custom logs written as part of a test in performance center?

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, loadrunner, vugen, hp-performance-center

I have a script which on running creates an ID and I want to have the list of IDs from the 30 mins test executed with this script. I want to run the test on performance center which uses LG to which I don't have access to? Basically how to get the files that are created by the script using functions like fopen fprintf after every test executed in performance center?

Answer (score 1):

lr_output_message()....this will send the data to the controller for tracking.  You could also use virtual table server or a queue service running in a cloud provider

realistically, you do not want to write data to the local load generator.  You will be turning the local drive into a bottleneck for the entire test as multiple users compete for access to the write head.   This is also why no, or log on error, is recommended for execution.